# Angular Universal pages do not show up in Google Analytics when the page is visited directly

Tags: angular, google-analytics, single-page-application, angular-universal, gtag.js

We’ve noticed that, with our Angular-14-with-Universal site, Google Analytics does not seem to register or pick up on clicks when interior pages are visited directly.

For example, if a user starts off on the Home Page (e.g., `https://example.com`), and then clicks around in there, subsequent clicks on links to interior pages WILL show up in our BigQuery database, usually as “page_view”.

However, if someone texts the link to an interior page to me — e.g., `https://example.com/posts/-SomePostId` and I click on that link… it will open in my default browser, but nothing shows up in BigQuery for that page’s id. If I then interact on the page once I’m on it, say, by hitting REFRESH, *then* I will start to see data in BigQuery; usually “session_start | first_visit | user_engagement”.

Is this normal behavior?

Is there a way to get Google Analytics to capture the clicks on direct links to posts?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE, JULY 2023: SOLUTION FOUND**

I now have things working after adding a bit of custom code into my website. Basically, the solution is to add a "page_view" event manually via code, and tie this to the Angular router's NavigationEnd event.

Now a "page_view" event occurs when a user clicks on a direct page link, and the event also occurs when users are clicking/navigating around in the website itself.

I based my changes on the instructions detailed in this article:
[How To Integrate Google Analytics in Angular 2022](https://www.ultimateakash.com/blog-details/Ii1DRGAKYAo=/How-To-Integrate-Google-Analytics-in-Angular-2022).

**GOOGLE ANALYTICS / GOOGLE TAG MANAGER UPDATES**

Because I am tracking the 'page_view' event manually, I had to go into Google Analytics and turn off "Enhanced Measurements", and also had to go into the "Google Tag Manager", and make sure I had turned off all events in "Manage automatic event detection". Otherwise, when I used the DebugView in Google Analytics, I noticed that I was getting 2 "page views" for every page I navigated to once I was in my web site. I'm not sure I had to turn off *every* option, but we are mainly concerned with page views for right now.

**CODE UPDATES**

**1) install types/gtag.js with npm**

`npm install @types/gtag.js --save-dev`

**2) ts.config.app.json**

Add "gtag.js" to "types":

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "out-tsc/app",
    "types": ["gtag.js"]
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

**3) app.module.ts**

Set "trackPageViews" to false for the GtagModule, since we will be tracking page views manually:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    ...,
    SharedModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    GtagModule.forRoot({ trackingId: environment.myTagMeasureId, trackPageviews: false })
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  ...etc...
```

**4) app.component.ts**

NOTE: Because I have Angular Universal (@nguniversal) installed on my Angular 14 app for Server Side Rendering, I inject my gtag a little differently, making sure to only add the script if we are in the browser.

```
import { Component, Inject, Renderer2, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser, DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
import { ActivatedRoute, NavigationEnd, Router, RouterState, TitleStrategy } from '@angular/router';
import { environment } from 'environments/environment';

declare const gtag: Function; // <------------Important: the declaration for gtag is required!

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'My Generic App Title';

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private titleStrategy: TitleStrategy,
    private renderer: Renderer2,
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private _document: any,
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object) {
      if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
        this.injectScripts();
        this.handleRouteEvents();
      }
  }

  injectScripts() {
    const gtmId = environment.myTagMeasureId;
    const gtmScriptTag = this.renderer.createElement('script');
    gtmScriptTag.type = 'text/javascript';
    gtmScriptTag.src = `https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=${gtmId}`;
    this.renderer.appendChild(this._document.head, gtmScriptTag);

    const gtagInitScript = this.renderer.createElement('script');
    gtagInitScript.type = 'text/javascript';
    gtagInitScript.text = `
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag() {
        dataLayer.push(arguments);
      }
      gtag('js', new Date());
      gtag('config', '${gtmId}', { 'send_page_view': false });
    `;
    this.renderer.appendChild(this._document.head, gtagInitScript);
  }

  handleRouteEvents() {
    this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        const p_path = event.urlAfterRedirects;
        const p_title = this.getTitle(this.router.routerState, this.router.routerState.root).join('-');
        gtag('event', 'page_view', { 
          'page_title': p_title ? p_title : p_path,
          'page_path': p_path,
          'page_location': this._document.location.href
        });
      }
    });
  }

  getTitle(state: RouterState, parent: ActivatedRoute): string[] {
    // We are using Angular 14, so we are able to take advantage of
    // using "title" in our app-routing.module.ts file, and utilizing
    // TitleStrategy to retrieve the title.
    const data = [];
    
    if (parent && parent.snapshot.data && this.titleStrategy.getResolvedTitleForRoute(parent.snapshot)) {
      data.push(this.titleStrategy.getResolvedTitleForRoute(parent.snapshot));
    }
    if (state && parent && parent.firstChild) {
      data.push(...this.getTitle(state, parent.firstChild));
    }
    return data;
  }
}
```

Comment: Weird, I only had to add my GA and GTM script to my `index.html` and [configure GTM to send NavigationEvents](https://medium.com/@pieterjandeclippel/angular-or-react-or-whatever-and-google-analytics-97342c909e61) to GA

Comment: Maybe things have changed a little bit after the migration from UA to GA4? Also, I will also bet that having Angular Universal / SSR installed adds a little bit of extra complexity into our web site. I wish this had all been a little easier :)